# How do I replicate the bootstrap mobile navbar toggle (without using bootstrap)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, hamburger-menu

I'm talking about the button that appears below certain screen widths which hides/unhides the menu when clicked (screenshot below). I'm trying to replicate its behavior on my website without resorting to using bootstrap (because I like to work without frameworks).

[image]

I've looked at the source code, but can't figure out exactly how it works, and what the most efficient way is to replicate the behaviour. From what I can tell it works with javascript by applying a hide/unhide class to the menu, activated by the button.

Would it be possible to replicate this with the css checkbox hack? Or is using javascript better?

Comment: @nailer: Ah, so it's called a hamburger-menu! I had no idea, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly simple:

- Add the hamburger menu icon
- Have a CSS class that makes the nav area active
- Make JS add/remove that class from the nav area
- Use CSS transitions to take care of the animation (they're more likely to be accelerated on a mobile device)

I like the implementation on http://purecss.io.

Also check out http://www.ymc.ch/sandbox/hamburger/mobile-menu-demo.html

Answer (score 0):

edit:

I misread question the first time.

I think you'd have a better time using javascript.

If you are using jquery you could use the toggle method.

```
$("#hide-show-button").click(function(){
    $(".nav").toggle();
});
```